# How to create an automated build after the DockerHub redesign?

Tags: docker

I miss the instructions that would describe how to do this after DockerHub 2.0:

https://blog.docker.com/2015/09/docker-hub-2-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It confused me for a while - don't click the big "Create" button. Instead select the "Create" drop-down menu in the top right and select "Create Automated Build".

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [How to set up automated builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#to-set-up-an-automated-build)